# Try statement issue R

Tags: r

Having an issue with this simple `try()` statement. All I would like it to do is if the number is not there or if an error comes up move to the next. New to R and I have some info in certain folders but missing some numbers between the range.

```
library(readr)

season <- c(2014:2014)
gamenumbers <- c(20300:21271)
#############################################
# TEAM NULL DF's
season_teamstatsadj5v5 <- NULL


print('NUll DFs Created')
##############################################
for(game in gamenumbers){
  try(
    print('Start Team')
    print(as.character(game)) 
    ###################################################################################################################
    # team_stats_adj_5v5_df Bind
    teamstatsadj5v5<-paste0('//LVS_DB/Users/Mike/Desktop/NHL_PBP/', season,'/', game, '/', game, '_teamstatsadj5v5.csv')
    teamstatsadj5v5_df <- read_delim(teamstatsadj5v5, delim = ',')
    season_teamstatsadj5v5 <- rbind(season_teamstatsadj5v5, teamstatsadj5v5_df)
  )
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write trycatch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r)

Comment: I saw that one, but I’m not sure how I would write it with a for Loop to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the corrected code you shared. `error` argument, which will handle the exception thrown should be indicated in `tryCatch` call. Please see as below:

```
library(readr)

season <- c(2014:2014)
gamenumbers <- c(20300:21271)
#############################################
# TEAM NULL DF's
season_teamstatsadj5v5 <- NULL


print('NUll DFs Created')
##############################################
for(game in gamenumbers){
  tryCatch({
    print('Start Team')
    print(as.character(game)) 
    ###################################################################################################################
    # team_stats_adj_5v5_df Bind
    teamstatsadj5v5<-paste0('//LVS_DB/Users/Mike/Desktop/NHL_PBP/', season,'/', game, '/', game, '_teamstatsadj5v5.csv')
    teamstatsadj5v5_df <- read_delim(teamstatsadj5v5, delim = ',')
    season_teamstatsadj5v5 <- rbind(season_teamstatsadj5v5, teamstatsadj5v5_df)
  }, error = function(e) {message(paste0(e, "\n"))})
}
```

Comment: That works great, thank you for taking the time to show me the tryCatch. Cant tell you how much time this will save me!